# How to use the following thesis style file?

Tags: thesis, cv

The following code is a part of CV in the thesis style file.

```
\def\vitae{\chapter*{CURRICULUM VITAE}\thispagestyle{plain}\pagestyle{plain}%
\vspace{1cm}
\fontsize{11}{12pt}\selectfont\begin{tabular}{@{}ccl}
    \hbox to 2cm{Name}&:& \@ename \\[5pt]
    \hbox to 2cm{Date of Birth}&:& \@ebirthday\\[5pt]
    \hbox to 2cm{Place of Birth}&:& \@ebirthplace\\[5pt]
    \hbox to 2cm{Address}&:& \@eaddr\\
  \end{tabular}}
\newlength{\temp@len}
\def\education#1{\vspace{1cm}
  \begin{center}\fontsize{14}{20pt}\selectfont EDUCATION
  \end{center}\vspace{.2cm}\settowidth{\temp@len}{#1}
  \begin{list}{}{\labelwidth=\temp@len\labelsep=.5cm
  \advance\temp@len by.5cm\leftmargin=\temp@len
  \def\makelabel##1{##1\hss}}}
\def\endeducation{\end{list}}

\def\experience#1{\vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{center}\fontsize{14}{20pt}\selectfont EXPERIENCES
  \end{center}\vspace{.2cm}\settowidth{\temp@len}{#1}
  \begin{list}{}{\labelwidth=\temp@len\labelsep=.5cm
  \advance\temp@len by.5cm\leftmargin=\temp@len
  \def\makelabel##1{##1\hss}}}
\def\endexperience{\end{list}}

\def\project#1{\vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{center}\fontsize{14}{20pt}\selectfont PROJECTS
  \end{center}\vspace{.2cm}\settowidth{\temp@len}{#1}
  \begin{list}{}{\labelwidth=\temp@len\labelsep=.5cm
  \advance\temp@len by.5cm\leftmargin=\temp@len
  \def\makelabel##1{##1\hss}}}
\def\endproject{\end{list}}

 \def\activityv#1{\vspace{0.0cm}
  \vspace{0cm}\settowidth{\temp@len}{#1}
  \begin{list}{}{\labelwidth=\temp@len\labelsep=0.2cm
  \advance\temp@len by.2cm\leftmargin=\temp@len
  \def\makelabel##1{##1\hss}}}
 \def\endactivityv{\end{list}}

 \def\activityj#1{\vspace{0cm}
  \vspace{0cm}\settowidth{\temp@len}{#1}
  \begin{list}{}{\labelwidth=\temp@len\labelsep=0.2cm
  \advance\temp@len by.1cm\leftmargin=\temp@len
  \def\makelabel##1{##1\hss}}}
 \def\endactivityj{\end{list}}

 \def\activityc#1{\vspace{0cm}
  \vspace{0cm}\settowidth{\temp@len}{#1}
  \begin{list}{}{\labelwidth=\temp@len\labelsep=0.2cm
  \advance\temp@len by0.1cm\leftmargin=\temp@len
  \def\makelabel##1{##1\hss}}}
 \def\endactivityc{\end{list}}
```

However, I don't know how to make section \education, \experience, and so on. Please, let me know how to make a list in those section. Thank you.

Comment: Please complete your code so we can compile a minimal document. That's much more useful than fragments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use it, I guess, something like this:

```
\begin{education}{longest}
  \item[b] c
  \item[longest] d
\end{education}
```

[image: education]

Although it is possible that code you've not shared might influence the appearance etc. etc. I've just stuck one of the fragments in a standard preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\temp@len}
\def\education#1{\vspace{1cm}
  \begin{center}\fontsize{14}{20pt}\selectfont EDUCATION
  \end{center}\vspace{.2cm}\settowidth{\temp@len}{#1}
  \begin{list}{}{\labelwidth=\temp@len\labelsep=.5cm
  \advance\temp@len by.5cm\leftmargin=\temp@len
  \def\makelabel##1{##1\hss}}}
\def\endeducation{\end{list}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{education}{longest}
  \item[b] c
  \item[longest] d
\end{education}
\end{document}
```